# Ternary operator and print

Tags: awk

What is wrong with below command

```
awk 'BEGIN {a = 5;b=6; (a==b)? print "a==b" : print "a!=b"}'
```

Output :

```
awk: BEGIN {a = 5;b=6; (a==b)? print "a==b" : print "a!=b"}
awk:                           ^ syntax error
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Like many other programming languages, `awk` distinguishes between expressions and statements. By and large, statements are actions that are carried out, while expressions are computations that result in a value.

The ternary operator in `awk`, like its counterpart in C where it comes from, is itself an expression (not a statement) that expects three other expressions as `expr1 ? expr2 : expr3`. `print` is a statement. It cannot be used where an expression is called for, hence the syntax error.

Have you tried `awk 'BEGIN {a = 5;b=6; print (a==b)? "a==b" : "a!=b"}'` ?

Using a statement where an expression is called for cannot make any sense. Statements don't return values. So when you have `condition ? stmt1 : stmt2`, what is the value computed by the ternary operator? If `condition` is false, it should be the value of `stmt2` but that's not a value, it's an action.

Comment: There are other languages where statements *do* return values (ruby comes to mind), but this is a perfect answer for the question.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, @glennjackman. I don't know Ruby so maybe I don't know what I'm talking about but my first thought on reading your comment was that guess that means that in Ruby [statements kind of *are* expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636503/whats-the-difference-of-statement-and-expression-in-ruby/9636655#9636655).

Comment: yes, you can do stuff like this useless example: `x = if true; print "yes"; else; print "no"; end`

Comment: I guess this negates the possibility of a construction like `(cond1) ? printf("str1") : printf("str2")`? Thanks explaining the subtleties of the ternary. EDIT: in fact, using the following ugly construction: `str = (cond1) ? sprintf("str1") : sprintf("str2"); printf("%s", str)` works, but at this point its almost as compact and much more clear to use if/else :)

Comment: consider using printf if you don't want to print void lines for unmatched conditions